# How to remove border from MUI text field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have used Input field from Material UI. I want to remove the border from it. I have tried using `border="none"` but it didn't remove.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peKdk.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextField 
   variant="standard"
   InputProps={{
     disableUnderline: true
   }}
/>
```

This will solve the issue. However, it may affect padding, use some css to set it according to your UI.

Comment: I had tried with the sx property and it wasn't working, the way you did it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the [variant](https://mui.com/api/text-field/#props) prop to filled or standard

The more you can work *with* mui styling rather than override it with custom CSS, the happier you’ll be long term.